# Higher PWM frequency than rated for device

Tags: pwm, motor-controller, damage

I've an electronic speed controller (ESC) rated for a maximum PWM frequency of 48kHz. As I was working on a project I was generating PWM. This PWM signal was connected to the ESC. After I noticed that one motor was spinning much harder than the other ones, I checked the signals as you can see in the image:

[image: PWM check]

PWM channel 0 is much denser than the other ones. After zooming in on the signal it was made up of small high frequency pulses.

[image: Zooming in]

I've found out that the cause was a bad level shifter.

What is the effect of a too high frequency (26MHz) for a lower rated system? Could this cause damage? My ESC is not working anymore.

**EDIT**

Closeup of the ESC MOSFETS

[image]

**EDIT 2**

Foto otherside of the ESC

[image]

Comment: Welcome! What failed in your ESC? Output stage?

Comment: Thank you! Currently I fixed the PWM output signal and there are 2 motors not spinning. I've switched the motors to check if that was the issue, but after replacement they won't spin as well. So I assumed that the ESC is dead. The ESC won't output any voltage when I measured with my multimeter (AC).

Comment: I see. That's a fairly macroscopic troubleshooting. If you share a schematic, it's easier to answer but if you pushed the frequency too high, I would expect dead time and overlap to be a problem for the output stage, possibly shorting a leg.

Comment: The manufacturer of the ESC did not make the schematic of the ESC available. I've checked with a possible shortage with checking the continuity on the legs. But this was not the case. What is dead time and overlap? It does not sound familiar to me.

Comment: Ah! Now I see your issue. What inputs does the ESC have? No indivudual MOSFET control I suppose?

Comment: The ESC has 4 inputs, PWM0 - PWM3. Each PWM is converted to a 3 fase AC output. So 1 motor is connected to the ESC with 3 wires. I count 12 MOSFETS underneath the heatsink.  So every ESC output has indeed an individual MOSFET control. I'm not able to check for continuity directly on the MOSFETS beceause of the large heatsink.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136516/discussion-between-winny-and-xander-van-den-berg).

Comment: Depends on everything. The ESC probably measures the PWM and then spins the motor at that speed. The PWM probably doesn't go straight through to control the motor. So you may have just confused the part that measures the PWM, and maybe it ran the motor at 100% speed instead of the speed you wanted.

Comment: Higher PWM frequency means more switching losses in the MOSFETs. 26MHz is so fast it would pretty much fry most power electronics so I kind of doubt it's actually doing that. Even tiny switching supplies can't run anywhere near that fast. It's the kind of thing you have to design for and put a lot of effort into doing so.

Comment: I don't think you can damage the ESC with such a high frequency, I'd rather think the ESC would simply not respond. One nasty thing of stepper motors is that they can be **demagnetized** under some conditions, one of them is blocking them while operating and maybe a higher than acceptable frequency, so when you say "two motors don't run", is it actually the motor or the ESC what is damaged?

Comment: @Joan I think so because when I changed the motor location and wired the "not" motor to a working ESC output there were no problems with the motor. And the motors that were working, were not working anymore on the new spots.

Comment: *If* the ESC passes the PWM to the output MOSFETS, chances are that the signal gets significantly low-pass filtered so the MOSFET spends more or the whole time in the linear region, where power dissipation is much higher than in saturation. Just a guess, if the output MOSFETS are not shorted it's likely something different...